# rename list of values to random values in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, replace

I have a column `sites` in pandas df. Data format: list of strings. I need to change the values of the column to randomly generated words. My data below:

```
row                    sites
1                    ["Elle", "Harpers", "Cosmo"]
2                    ["Elle", "Vogue"]
3                    ["Cosmo"]
```

Desired output:

```
row                    sites
1                     ["KLD", "GHL", "JGF"]
2                     ["KLD", "VGO"]
3                     ["JGF"]
```

I should be able to reverse the names after also or have them saved in the format `VGO = Vogue`
I wanted to use `numpy.random.randint` but seems like this method is only for integers. What is the fastest way to generate the names rather than hardcode using `replace`?

Comment: do you have a fixed set of sites that you know beforehand?   Or you want to generate the codes on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with the list of all 3 uppercase letters [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
upperletters = map(chr, range(65, 91))
print(np.random.choice(list(map(''.join, 
                                combinations_with_replacement(upperletters, 3))), 
                       size=8, replace=False))
#['JPZ' 'SSU' 'AQW' 'GKQ' 'AIZ' 'UYY' 'IJS' 'AOR']
```

Now, to change in the data, you can do `explode`, and `map` using a dictionary with the equivalent.

```
s = df['sites'].explode()
codes = np.random.choice(list(map(''.join, 
                                  combinations_with_replacement(map(chr, range(65, 91)),
                                                                3))), 
                         size=s.nunique(), replace=False)
d = {word:code for word, code in zip(s.unique(), codes)}
print(d) #so in d you keep the correspondence
{'Elle': 'IVV', 'Harpers': 'DDW', 'Cosmo': 'DKM', 'Vogue': 'MRV'}

df['sites'] = s.map(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df)
   row            sites
0    1  [IVV, DDW, DKM]
1    2       [IVV, MRV]
2    3            [DKM]
```

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I need and saves the records. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# use sample data to create data frame
data = [(1, ["Elle", "Harpers", "Cosmo"]),
        (2, ["Elle", "Vogue"]),
        (3, ["Cosmo"])]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['row', 'sites'])

# get unique sites
unique_sites = df.explode('sites').loc[:, 'sites'].sort_values().unique()

# build map from actual site to masked site - could use full alphabet below
random.seed(123456)
site_to_scrambled = {
    site: ''.join(random.choices('ABCDEFGHI', k=4))
    for site in unique_sites }

def convert(sites, site_to_scrambled):
    return [site_to_scrambled[site] for site in sites]

# apply the conversion 
# (keep both sites and sites_scrambled to verify)
df['sites_scrambled'] = df['sites'].apply(
    lambda x: convert(x, site_to_scrambled))
print(df)

   row                   sites     sites_scrambled
0    1  [Elle, Harpers, Cosmo]  [AFAC, BCEB, HHAB]
1    2           [Elle, Vogue]        [AFAC, AIDF]
2    3                 [Cosmo]              [HHAB]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately, I have an error: `NoneType Object is not irritable`

Comment: Glad you received / accepted a response that met the requirements.  My version works on my machine (Python 3.8.5 and pandas 1.1.0).  If you post the problematic data, I'll take a look.  Works on my machine: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/